# visual studio 2008 software assurance to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, licensing, upgrade

Does anyone know the MSDN licensing rules around upgrade from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010 if I were to buy VS 2008 now?

I will not be able to get budget for the 2010 one too, but I have heard there are software assurances in place if you have MSDN subscriptions.

I will not be able to get an MSDN subscription, so is there a way of upgrading for free when vs 2010 comes out in March next year?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Software Assurance" is a Microsoft program for "Enterprise" and "Select" volume licensees, and it allows you to get free upgrades for the software until the end of the Software Assurance contract (which is usually 2 years). But unless you are at a company that purchases lots of Microsoft software and already has a Volume Agreement with them, you will not be able to get the Software Assurance.

I don't know of any other program that allows you to get free upgrades for the next version. Visual Studio 2010 is expected to be released in a couple months--can you wait until then for your purchase?

Comment: Do you have any officially link from Microsoft verifying this information?

Comment: This is the first result that Google gave me: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/default.aspx

Read all about it!

Comment: Thanks for the resource.  This has been helpfully with answering Microsoft licensing questions.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd wait until VS2010 is released (March 22 2010) before I bought anything.

You can use the [VS2010 beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try/default.mspx) to get things up and running until then.

The beta even includes a ["go-live" license](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2009/10/19/going-live-with-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx) so you can deploy your product immediately, if you're really desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds too good to be true... but look at [WebSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/) from Microsoft if you are an independent developer. Free MSDN for 3 years if you meet certain criteria.

For businesses try [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/).

Answer (score 0):

And of course [trials are for 90 days](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/default.mspx) if you haven't already trialed out 2008. But VS2010 won't quite be out by then, but its good to know.